# Avoid duplicates with the yield keword?

Tags: python, generator

Is it possible to avoid duplicates in a yield generator?

For example

```py
def foo():
    for i in (1,1,1,2,3,4,5):
        #check if "i" have not been "yielded" yet?
        yield i 

gen = foo()
numbers = list(gen)
print(numbers)

>>>[1,2,3,4,5]
```

`numbers = list(gen)` is cheating, the goal is to do it within the function

Comment: If the values are hashable, you can keep a set of the ones you've yielded so far.  But keep in mind that values that compare equal are considered the same, even if they have different types (e.g. `1`, `1.0`, `True`, `(1+0j)`, `Fraction(1,1)`, `Decimal(1)` are all considered equal).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define `foo` as follows

```
def foo():
    seen = set()
    for i in (1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5):
        if i not in seen:
            seen.add(i)
            yield i
```

---

Keep in mind that sets are **unordered**. If order doesn't matter to you, then you can use:

```
def foo(lst):
    return (v for v in set(lst))
```

as pointed out by @TomKarzes in the comments. If you need the result to be in order then you'll have to stick to the initial formulation.

Comment: `for i in (1,1,1,2,3,4,5):` is just for the example

Comment: You can simplify `foo` by using a generator:  `def foo(lst): return (v for v in set(lst))`  That returns a generator.